# style not being applied to anchor element properly

Tags: css

When I try to set the color of the link element, using the class name like this :

```
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.classList.add('f');
```

```
 .f {
    color: white !important;

  }
```

The link still remains blue
but when I apply it generally using the anchor tag

```
 a {
    color: white !important;

  }
```

the link text is turned to white, why is that ? What should I do ?

I wanted the link color of my anchor tag to be displayed white, but when I style it with my classname it gets displayed blue, but if I use the general anchor tag the style is applied

Comment: Can you share more information? This code shouldn't fail

Comment: Please can you include the rest of the file code and where each file is being imported if the code doesn't currently exist in the same file?

Answer (score 0):

Here You Go

```js
function addElement() {
            // create a new anchor element
            const newAnchor = document.createElement("a");

            // and give it some content
            const newContent = document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!");

            // add the text node to the newly created anchor
            newAnchor.appendChild(newContent);
            newAnchor.classList.add('f');

            // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
            const currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1");
            document.body.insertBefore(newAnchor, currentDiv);
        }
```

```css
.f {
            color: red !important;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<button onclick="addElement()">Click for generate anchor</button>
    <div id="div1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the 'a' attribute is not getting the class value.

So instead we can use the following logic to set the class value to 'a' tag:

```js
let link = document.createElement('a');
link.innerText = "your link";
link.classList.add('f');
link.setAttribute('href', '#');
document.body.appendChild(link);
```

```css
body{
  background:black;
}
.f{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">other link</a>
<br>
<br>
```

Also no need to add `!important` anymore

Comment: This will apply the class to every anchor element in the document, not just the anchor element the question is referring to.

Comment: @Tom, I got what you were trying to say. Check now.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should always ignore `!important` it should not be used frequently until it is important, as it gives element the highest specificity and makes `CSS` harder to maintain. and in this code

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.classList.add('f');
```

you are only creating an element but it is not made in `DOM` you should append it in the body first like this

```
document.body.append(link)
```

Now your anchor is added in the `DOM` with class first it was not added. Now your `CSS` using class selector will work.

Answer (score -1):

```js
document.getElementById("a1").style.color = "red";
```

```html
<a href='#' id="a1">Change Text Color</a>
```

```html
you can use inline style to change the text color inside anchor tag.<br>
<a href="#" style="color: red;">Hello</a>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - @yamuna may want to create elements and add classes dynamically as suggested by their use of JavaScript.